# Is this a bug of php? How would you 'patch' it?

Tags: php

I'm dealing with this simple script in **php** :

```
$a = array('la','co');
foreach ($a as $unboldeda){
    $boldeda[] = '<b style="color: teal;">'.$unboldeda.'</b>';
}
$c = 'land of copper';
echo '<a href="#">'.str_replace($a, $boldeda, $d=$c).'</a>';
```

It should result into
 **la**nd of **co**pper

but it results into:

**co**lor: teal;">land of **co**pper

bacause `str_replace()` not only replaces the value of $d, but of $c as well, hence in the second iteration $c will also contain html tags. In my view this doesn't make much sense for a programming language. How would you work around this?

Comment: Replace with `strtr`

Comment: This behaviour is warned about on the manual page for that function: http://php.net/str_replace As to why, the alternative is significantly harder to implement.

Comment: may you please tell me the name of the contributor or the number of the contribute you refer to? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with `strtr`:

```
$a = array('la','co');
foreach ($a as $unboldeda){
    $boldeda[$unboldeda] = '<b style="color: teal;">'.$unboldeda.'</b>';
}
$c = 'land of copper';
echo '<a href="#">'.strtr($c, $boldeda).'</a>';
```

Explanation:

your line

```
echo '<a href="#">'.str_replace($a, $boldeda, $d=$c).'</a>';
```

has **nothing** to do with `$d` or `$c`. 
`str_replace` changes items from `$a` to `$boldeda` in a value, which is a result of operation `$d=$c`. Result ot this assignment is string `land of copper`, your `$d` and `$c` are both **untouched**. You can check this by **outputting** them.

Going further, on a `str_replace` manpage you will see that it has **Replacement order gotcha** which tells you that:

> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements.

So, `str_replace` first replaces `la` with tag, which has `color` in it,
and second `str_replace` replaces `co` with a new substitution. Unfortunately, word `color` has `co` **too**, so, `str_replace` replaces it too, because it does not "remember" what has been already replaced, and what not.

Comment: unfortunately it isn't, it causes $boldeda being no longer bolded nor styled :-(

Comment: `boldela` is __array__. And __fortunately__, it is https://3v4l.org/QZV4l

Comment: I know, but can't follow you. What should I do to it?

Comment: @G.ManJi What's wrong with u_mulder's answer? It works.

Comment: No no, u_mulder's answer is ok, now I've understood. I didn't see this modification $boldeda[$unboldeda] - it works now

Comment: @u_mulder A well-detailed/explained solution, *bravo*. The additional edit was spot on.

Comment: @u_mulder: actually your explaination makes sense and I've just understood how strtr works. But just for my curiosity. Is str_replace bugged as a function? I mean at least with arrays, because with single variables it works egregiously

Comment: What does it mean - bugged? It does its' work - replaces items with other items. No one promised you that this function will remember what was previously changed.

Comment: @u_mulder GOTCHA!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think this part does

```
$d=$c
```

It assigns `$d` to the value of `$c` and then returns that value.

Just do one thing at a time

Comment: It is the same when I put $d=$c outside and $d only inside str_replace

Comment: @G.ManJi - That would do the same. It's identical as just passing `$c` to str_replace(). There's no reason to involve `$d` at all.